# Copying range of cells from on Excel to another with Python

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I would like to copy a range of cells from one Excel file to another (found an example at [Copying Data into Excel](https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html) and modified it to my needs), but get an error message (can be seen below). Data is copied to destination file, but I can't get it to save and close the file.
I have tried to create and rename and also delete save_file, but this won't help.
What am I missing here?

```
import win32com.client as win32


# Define the full path for the data file file
data_file = "C:/2020/data.xlsx"

# Define the full path for the final output file
save_file = "C:/2020/result.xlsx"

# Define the template file
template_file = "C:/2020/template.xlsx"


# Use com to copy the files around
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False


# Template file
wb_template = excel.Workbooks.Open(template_file)

# Open up the data file
wb_data = excel.Workbooks.Open(data_file)

# Copy from the data file (select all data in V2:V22 columns)
wb_data.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("V2:V22").Select()

# Paste into the template file
excel.Selection.Copy(Destination=wb_template.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C7"))

# Must convert the path file object to a string for the save to work
wb_template.SaveAs(str(save_file))


wb_template.Close()
wb_data.Close()
excel.DisplayAlerts = True
excel.Quit()`
```

Error message:

```
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-ffb7fd7b0160> in <module>
     33 
     34 # Must convert the path file object to a string for the save to work
---> 35 wb_template.SaveAs(str(save_file))
     36 
     37 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\_Workbook.py in SaveAs(self, Filename, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local, WorkIdentity)
    286                         , FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup
    287                         , AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout
--> 288             , Local, WorkIdentity)
    289 
    290         def SaveAsXMLData(self, Filename=defaultNamedNotOptArg, Map=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\\//2020/24D8CD00'. There are several possible reasons:\n\n• The file name or path does not exist.\n• The file is being used by another program.\n• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: ```The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.``` this could be a solution. Is the workbook with same name open? try going to task manager and kill all EXCEL.exe before running your code

Comment: @Yash Shah I restarted my computer, but unfortunately this did not help. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `save_file = "C:/2020/result.xlsx"` to `save_file = "C:\\2020\\result.xlsx"`

Comment: Tried raw string `r'C:/2020/result.xlsx'` it didn't work. So tried escaping `/`, it didn't work either. But `\\\` works. Please someone explain. Thanks.